# Kafka *Offset* exceptions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The kafka exceptions `NoOffsetForPartitionException` and `OffsetOutOfRangeException` are Thrown when the offset for a set of partitions is invalid (either undefined or out of range), and no reset policy has been configured.

Can you describe execution scenarios that cause these exceptions to be raised?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One example - `consumer.seek` is called for a partition offset that doesn't exist.

Other example - a consumer group was paused for some long duration, then resumes after its stored offsets have been deleted due to topic retention policies. In this case, the `auto.offset.reset` policy is taken into account to either seek to the latest/earliest available offset.

Comment: Thank for the clear answer. When the consumer group is rebalancing and the group is not in the STABLE state (e.g., CompletingRebalance, PreparingRebalance) does that affect value of the offsets (end, committed). I am using the admin API to query the offsets during times where the group might undergo reblancing, and sometimes seeing inconsistent values? any idea?

Comment: If the `auto.offset.reset` policy recommits the earliest/latest offset during a rebalance, then the offsets will change, yes